# Pending Request and Notification with RoboSpice

Tags: android, notifications, request, robospice

In my application, I use the (amazing) library RoboSpice with Retrofit. 
I have an Activity where I execute dependent requests each other ie for example In my Request1Listener I call my Request2, in my Request2Listener I call Request 3 etc... I have 2 questions :

How do I know that all of the request executed in my Activity is completed? I tried to check in every listener if the number of pending request is zero (getSpiceManager().getPendingRequestCount() == 0) but it doesn' work.

If the user leaves the activty for one reason or another, I would like to create a notification informing him of the progress of data with a percentage (I created the percentage calculation algorithm), and when all requests are completed (hence my question 1) I can also warn the user with a new notification.

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for my english, I'm a French developer

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `com.octo.android.robospice.request.listener.RequestProgressListener` for that purpose.

However, storing the intermediate state is something you should do with your own logic - there is no specific support for that in RoboSpice. For example, a singleton manager that would accept the latest state of your requests and which would know whether all of them are finished.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In My Activity I implemented *SpiceServiceListener* and in my *onRequestProcessed* I check if *getSpiceManager().getPendingRequestCount()* & *getSpiceManager().getRequestToLaunchCount()* are equal to 0. 
Does this ensures that all requests are completed my Activity ?

Comment: Yes, that seems like a possible solution (haven't used it personally, so make sure to test extensively), although you don't necessarily need to use a `RequestProgressListener`. I think you can safely go with a normal `RequestListener` in that case.